# How to tell VBA to go to Add-In tab and press a certain button?

Tags: vba, excel, button, tabs, add-in

I have a rather complex Add-In in my Excel setup by my company, with menu and all that stuff. What it does, it extracts SAP Data from Database. The Add-in is password protected so i cannot make adjustents from within it. I wonder if I can create a VBA that will access the needed buttons in the Add-in Menu to refresh everytime I need?

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can call them from the addin i belive, so if you know the function call from the addin, say ADDIN.SAP_DOWNLOAD, you can call this, otherwise i'd look at "clicking ribbon buttons vba"

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Add-In VBE code is locked and I have no rights of reading or editing. Is there other way to look at this issue? Cheers!

Comment: You could change the addin to .zip file and look at the XML for the UI, to get the OnAction value.

Comment: I have read that it is possible to enable the Add-In Reference in VBA Tools-References so that VBA can actually see the functions. Which I did, but I cannot seem to enable it for all future excel files that I am having opened. Any idea on that?

Comment: Do you mean adding as a reference?  if so you can do dim x as addinname, then use x.function1, x.function2 etc.